# Install vim-latex on Ubuntu 15

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin

I've tried to install vim-latex via:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-latexsuite
vim-addon-manager install latex-suite
```

I have added to my .vimrc

```
filetype plugin on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

When I start vim with a *.tex file I get no menus. I first tried to manually install and that also did not work. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: If you do `:h ls_1` after opening a .tex file, what happens?

Comment: I get the help pages for the suite.

Comment: Then the plugin seems to be detected and loaded fine. What is it you expect? (I have not used it, so I don't know what these "menus" you are talking of are.) What about other functionality that the plugin offers?

Comment: When you open a .tex file you should get some menus, template options, etc.

Comment: I see. What about other functionality, like [mappings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart.html#lsq-insert-environment)?

Comment: These seem to be functioning.

Comment: Just to confirm: the `.tex` files you're editing are non-existent, right? What if you run `:TTemplate`?

Comment: Aha this works!

Comment: :TTemplate does the trick (still no menus but I suppose everything else is in line)

Comment: In my system `vim` has no menus; `gvim` shows them by default. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43526/is-it-possible-to-create-and-use-menus-in-terminal-based-vim and `:h console-menus`