# Installing vim latex-suite plugin?

Tags: vim, latex, gvim, vim-plugin

I have installed `vim-gtk` and `vim-addons-manager` on my ubuntu 14.04, and also the `latex-suite` plugin.  This I did with

```
sudo apt-get install vim-latexsuite
vim-addon-manager enable latex-suite
```

which put all the files into my `~/.vim` directory.  However, I can't seem to make that plugin known to gvim when I start.  I have two issues:

1. The `:scriptnames` command gives me just one screen's worth of output, and any key immediately kills the buffer, so I can't scroll through it and see what is, and what isn't, installed.  How can I scroll through this buffer?
2. I have got the help of latex-suite installed, so that `:h latex-suite` gives me the helpfile.  But the command `:TTemplate` as recommended here: [Install vim-latex on Ubuntu 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676173/install-vim-latex-on-ubuntu-15) produces an error, that it's "not an editor command".

Note that of my two commands above, the second is supposed to be unnecessary; once `vim-latexsuite` is installed using `apt-get` it should run automatically.  But it didn't, and doesn't.

Any advice would be very welcome!

Comment: If you press enter or down arrow, you will be able to see the rest of the script names. `:TTemplate` or whatever, it will executed only if such editor command is found. By default, editor commands don't start with capital letter. So, it must be a user defined or plugin command. That command might call another function like `:call Template`. You need to check whether such command exists or not.

Comment: Thank you, but no - pressing enter, or arrow keys, or *any key at all* immediately kills the `:scriptnames` buffer.   I'm trying to see if I can load `latex-suite` as a plugin using `vim-plug` but so far without success.

Comment: Do you need to use vim-gtk in particular rather than vim-gnome? it seems to work with the latter (at least, for me)

Comment: Well, I use kde, so I thought that vim-gtk would be OK.  But the GUI (gtk, gnome, athena) shoudn't make any difference to the handling of plugins.